# SceneKit - How to set size of SCNText

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

This is my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    scnView.scene = SCNScene()
    scnView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    createText()
}

func createText() {
    let text = SCNText(string: "Hello, world!", extrusionDepth: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: text)
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

I can't seem to be able to access the `textSize` property by

```
text.textSize = 18
```

Or when I tried to change the font of the text, it didn't work either.

What went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I fail to understand why

```
text.textSize = 18
```

even compiles, as the SCNText textSize property is defined a an CGSize (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext/1523680-textsize)

textSize is the "size of the smallest bounding rectangle containing the text".

Also, remember that the screen size of your text, which is a SCNNode just like any other, will depend on the view characteristics of your 3D world. You can enlarge the SCNNode in many ways, such as using

```
text.scale = SCNVector3Make(xScaleValue,yXcaleValue,zScaleValue)
```

And to actually set the font that you'll be using :

```
text.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica",size: 12)
```

Comment: I get it, instead of setting the text size, I should also set the correct camera location. Also, `text` doesn't have a `scale` property, the node it belongs to does.